# can't figure out why this doesn't add row and cell to table

Tags: javascript, html

When I run the script I don't get any errors in the console, it just won't add a row and cell. I need to add a row and cell when more than one row of results are found. Do I have errors???? This is a small bit of the code

```
var txt = "";
var i = 0;                   

for (state in stateMiles) {
    i++;
    var x =(stateMiles[state]);
   (stateMiles[state])= parseFloat(x);  

    function appendRow() {

        var tbl = document.getElementById("table"), // table reference
            row = tbl.insertRow(tbl.rows.length),      // append table row
            i;

        // insert table cells to the new row
        for (i = 0; i < tbl.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
            createCell(row.insertCell(i), i, 'row');
        }
    }

    $("#results").append
    $(".state" + i).append(state);
    $(".mile" + i).append(stateMiles[state]);
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `appendRow()`?

Comment: What is `$("results").append` supposed to do? You haven't supplied an argument saying what to append?

Comment: Why do you define the function inside the loop? Just define the function once outside the loop, and call it in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet is a mess. Are you declaring a function inside a for loop?

Don't do that.

This is the kind of thing that MVC style libraries like Angular, React, etc all really excel at, but if you're looking to do this, here's some code that should help.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  
  var stateMiles = [
    {
      state: "CO",
      miles: 5082
    },
    {
      state: "TX",
      miles: 582085
    },
    {
      state: "IL",
      miles: 9852
    }
  ];
  
  var tbody = $( "#my_table tbody" );
  for( state_idx in stateMiles ) {
    
    var state = stateMiles[ state_idx ];
    tbody.append( $( "#row_template" ).html().replace( "{{state}}", state.state ).replace( "{{miles}}", state.miles ) );
    
  }
  
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <table id="my_table">
      <thead>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Miles</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        
      </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <script type="text/html" id="row_template">
      <tr>
        <td>{{state}}</td>
        <td>{{miles}}</td>
      </tr>
    </script>

  </body>
</html
```